# Не работает jquery в Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, почему код не работает в Safari устройствах? на андроидах, виндовс все норм

```js
$("body").on('click', '.multiselect__content .multiselect__element', function() {
  let lval = $(this).attr('data-value');
  let lhtml = $(this).html();

  $('body').find(".size-select option").removeAttr('selected');
  $('body').find('.multiselect__content .multiselect__element').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('multiselect__option--selected');
  });

  $('body').find(".size-select option[value=" + lval + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
  $('body').find(".multiselect__content .multiselect__element[data-value=" + lval + "]").toggleClass('multiselect__option--selected');
  $('body').find(".multiselect__tags .multiselect__single").html(lhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select name="option[222086]" id="input-option222086" class="multiselect size-select">
    <option value="0"> --- Выберите --- </option>
    <option value="227342">M
    </option>
    <option value="227341">S
    </option>
    <option value="226574">L
    </option>
  </select>

  <div tabindex="0" class="multiselect dropdown">
    <div class="multiselect__select"></div>
    <div class="multiselect__tags  dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="multiselect__single"> Выберите размер</span>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="multiselect__content-wrapper dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <ul class="multiselect__content" style="display: inline-block;">
        <li class="multiselect__element" data-value="0">
          <span class="multiselect__option">
                                                                        Выберите размер
                                                                    </span>
        </li>
        <li class="multiselect__element" data-value="227342">
          <span class="multiselect__option">
                                                                        M
                                                                    </span>
        </li>
        <li class="multiselect__element" data-value="227341">
          <span class="multiselect__option">
                                                                        S
                                                                    </span>
        </li>
        <li class="multiselect__element" data-value="226574">
          <span class="multiselect__option">
                                                                        L
                                                                    </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? Что должен делать Ваш код?

Comment: И что написано в консоли браузера?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9y5knufL/ работает в Safari 13 на Mac, Safari на iPadOS и iOS

Answer (score 1):

https://jquery.com/browser-support/ читай  здесь 
Если вам требуется поддержка старых браузеров, таких как Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x или Safari 5.1+, используйте jQuery 1.12 .

Comment: в новом сафари не работает и ios